# How to save multiple objects creating a different row for each item, in realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

What I want to do is be able to save to realm multiple objects in a tableview at once. I have a simple tableview, with a simple label, where I have a bar button that can send it to edit mode. In edit mode I want the ability to save all the objects that I selected in edit mode into realm.

I don't think it is so much as saving an array of objects, because when I tried all it did was create a single empty row in Realm.

this is my main viewController:

```
import UIKit
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,



UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var realm: Realm!

let num = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
var testingBool = false
var values: [String] = []

@IBOutlet weak var itemBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
    realm = try! Realm()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return num.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.txtLbl?.text = "\(num[indexPath.row])"
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if testingBool == true {
        values.append(num[indexPath.row])
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if testingBool == true {
        if let index = values.index(of: num[indexPath.row]) {
            values.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    testingBool = !testingBool
    if testingBool == true {
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        itemBtn.title = "cancel"
    } else if testingBool == false {
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false
        itemBtn.title = "item"
    }

}

@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if testingBool == true {
        favorite(label: values)
    }
}

func favorite(label: [String]) {
    let saveTest = SaveTest()
    try? realm!.write {
        for string in num {
            realm.add(saveTest)
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is the realm model:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import Realm

class SaveTest: Object {

@objc dynamic var label = ""

convenience init(label: String) {
    self.init()
    self.label = label
}
}
```

What I want to happen is fill Realm with the multiple rows that I have selected. 
An example of this is if I select the row of 4 and 5 I want to save each of them at the same time to realm, but them being different objects in realm, so it would create 2 rows with one being 4 and the other being five.

The reason I want to do this is also in the future to be able to save multiple selected objects to a database that has more than one column. If in this hypothetical I have four columns: id, Number, Written, and Roman, I want to save the data of each selected row to this new realm database.

The example of that would be if I selected 4 and 5 again, it creates 2 new rows in realm with one of the rows having "4" "Four" and IV, and the id in each column while the other row has "5" "Five"  V and the id in each column.

I hope I was not being too vague and confusing. If i can help in any way please ask. 
Thank you

---

Update:

Through searching through stack overflow and with the help of koropok I figured out how to save multiple arrays at once. I found that when you want to loop through multiple arrays at once you use zip().

this is the new realm saving function that I have. BTW it has its own corresponding realm class.

```
    func realmed(label: [String], romanNum: [String], txt: [String]) {
    try? realm!.write {
        for (stringOne, (stringTwo, stringThree)) in zip(label, zip(romanNum, txt)) {
            let realmed = Realmed(label: stringOne, romanNum: stringTwo, txt: stringThree)
            realm.add(realmed)
        }
    }
}
```

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to init your SaveTest object with the label within the loop, not before it.

```
func favorite(label: [String]) {

    try? realm!.write {

       for string in label {

            let saveTest = SaveTest(label: string)
            realm.add(saveTest)
        }
    }
}
```